# Leading by example and requesting feedback/collaboration

Tags: discussion, specific-question

In this [question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/13254/stages-of-the-bardo) I recieved several answers that were far from what I asked, and had very little effort put into them.

After having one bounty expire unrewarded, the user Ryan put a second bounty on the question.

I am working on providing a through answer to my original question, and was wondering if any feedback could be provided. 
There is still a lot of detail to be added, and I am going to continue working on it until it is as complete as my knowledge and resources will allow.

I really have not provided new information to myself, as the book I am using is an old favorite of mine. I was hoping that with feedback anyone that knows more about these stages could help me edit and add detail to the answer.

I have a 4 CD lecture on the Bardo given by [Robert Thurman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Thurman) that I plan on re-listening to tonight, and adding any new details appropriate from it to the answer.

Comment: I wonder, if you asked Tenzin Dorje e.g. by [posting an '@'](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/139866) message, e.g. in [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34594/karma-in-mahayana), whether he might be able to recommend any relevant reference or at least explain why he couldn't.

Comment: @ChrisW that is part of my worry.  I know not all the bardo teachings are considered public

Comment: Here's the chat room you created: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34692/bardo-discussion